# I can not send a post to django rest framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I created a serializer to post a results, but when I try to use postman it says that the value 'enrollment_id' is null:

views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics

from .serializers import ResponseSerializer


class ResponseCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ResponseSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
class ResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Response
        fields = (
            'enrollment_id',
            'evaluation_id',
            'question_id',
            'question_component_id',
            'user_id',
        )
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ResponseCreate.as_view()),
]
```

In the postman post body I send the following json:

```
{
    "enrollment_id": 1,
    "user_id": 2,
    "question_component_id": 2,
    "question_id": 1,
    "evaluation_id": 1
}
```

Error postman:

```
IntegrityError at /response/
null value in column "enrollment_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (9, null, null, null, null, null).
```

view

[image]

Edit:

Model Response:

```
class Response(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        )
    enrollment = models.ForeignKey(
        Enrollment, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        )
    evaluation = models.ForeignKey(
        Evaluation,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        )
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        )
    question_component = models.ForeignKey(
        Question_Component,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        )
```

Comment: Please, share your `urls.py` and the ModelViewSet

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
Your serializer need not add '_id' after the Model fields.
It should be like this:

```
class ResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Response
        fields = (
            'enrollment',
            'evaluation',
            'question',
            'question_component',
            'user',
        )
```

Now try seding the modified JSON via Postmen:

```
{
  "enrollment": 1,
  "user": 2,
  "question_component": 2,
  "question": 1,
  "evaluation": 1
}
```

---

You need to define a `queryset` in your view:

```
class ResponseCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Response.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ResponseSerializer
```

Comment: same error, i send the json with the values and an error that can not have null value

Comment: Can you also post the model definition of `Response`?

Comment: I added the model response

Comment: worked perfectly, I thought I had to put the field by the name that is in the database table, now I understand, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to indicate in your url patter the methods that are going to be allowed:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ResponseCreate.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
]
```

I can see in the error you get that `GET method is not allowed, that's because you didn't indicate Django to allow it.

Try this view:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import ResponseSerializer

class ResponseCreate(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Response.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ResponseSerializer
```

**ModelViewSet** has already the proper response for al methods, but you have to indicate in your url pattern which ones are allowed.

Comment: The method is not allowed even, but the form below divert appear fields to send the post.

Comment: I even took the question because I want to solve the post request first, this I see later

Comment: Share your view, please